# Why doesn't simultaneous equations work to find co-efficients of a cubic that passes through four points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, cubics

I'm trying to find the equation of a cubic that passes through three specific points (technically it's four but that point is y-intercept). The equation would look something like this:
$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+25.8$ (25.8 is the given y-intercept mentioned above) 
The points are: $(0,25.8),(19.3,7.3),(48.9,30),(38.6,26)$ 
I set it up by starting with the first three equations: 
$7.3=a19.3^3+b19.3^2+c19.3+25.8$ 
$30=a48.9^3+b48.9^2+c48.9+25.8$ 
$26=a38.6^3+b38.6^2+c38.6+25.8$ 
I have tried using three simultaneous equations but when I graph the function it only goes through the y-intercept (obviously) and one of the three points. Is there something I'm doing wrong or can I just not solve this that way?

Comment: Of course you’re doing something wrong, but we cannot tell you what it is if you don’t post the details.

Comment: right sorry, I'll edit it

Comment: Simultaneous equations aren't really something one can easily solve by graphing. "Technically four points" is important; three points (with different $x$ coordinates) have an infinite number of cubics going through them. How are you setting up your system of equations?

Comment: I solve it algebraically and then I graph it. Checking algebraically also yields the same results. It is 4 points its just one of them doesn't matter because its the y-intercept.

Comment: @sirOrange17 "*I solve it algebraically*" $\;-\;$ You must have an error there, but we cannot guess what or where if you don't post the steps. Note that the coefficients of the result have quite different magnitudes, so you have to work with enough precision to get the correct values.

Comment: You still haven’t told us how you “solved” this system of three linear equations.

Comment: I just ran your equations through the systems of equations calculator on WA and the coefficients it produced gave me a graph that runs through all four points properly... The cubic coefficient is _very_ small so your calculation is going to need to retain at least six decimal places in order to fit the points well.

Comment: thanks everyone. that must have been it. My precision was to small. @boojum how did you get WA to interpret your equations correctly, it kept saying invalid inputs or making the co-efficients exponents or just not giving me an answer.

Comment: Ask it for "systems of equations calculator" and the prompts will show you the format.  I copy-pasted your equations as they appear here, except that you will have to replace the variables with $ \ x , y , z \ \ ; \ $ it won't  like $ \ a, b, c \ $ as variables. Also place the variables _after_ the coefficients of the equations, not before them.

Comment: @boojum ahhhh I was using a, b, c. thanks mate.

Comment: @sirOrange17 Or just [`interpolate (0,25.8),(19.3,7.3),(48.9,30),(38.6,26)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=interpolate+%280%2C25.8%29%2C%2819.3%2C7.3%29%2C%2848.9%2C30%29%2C%2838.6%2C26%29)

Comment: @dxiv yep I've looked at another question on stack exchange about Lagrange Interpolation and that's worked now as well.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks!  I didn't know WA had a "button" for that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\large\color{red}{\text{You do not learn anything using blindly any software !!!}}$$

Making the problem more gereral for four data points, the equations are
$$y_1=a \,x_1^3+b \,x_1^2+c\, x_1+d \tag 1$$
$$y_2=a \,x_2^3+b \,x_2^2+c\, x_2+d \tag 2$$
$$y_3=a \,x_3^3+b \,x_3^2+c\, x_3+d \tag 3$$
$$y_4=a \,x_4^3+b \,x_4^2+c\, x_4+d \tag 4$$

So
$$y_2-y_1=a(x_2^3-x_1^3)+b(x_2^2-x_1^2)+c(x_2-x_1)$$
$$y_3-y_2=a(x_3^3-x_2^3)+b(x_3^2-x_2^2)+c(x_3-x_2)$$
$$y_4-y_3=a(x_2^4-x_3^3)+b(x_4^2-x_3^2)+c(x_4-x_3)$$

Use the factorization and divide
$$\color{red}{z_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=a(x_2^2+x_1x_2+x_1^2)+b(x_2+x_1)+c \tag 5$$
$$\color{red}{z_2}=\frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}=a(x_3^2+x_2x_3+x_2^2)+b(x_3+x_2)+c \tag 6$$
$$\color{red}{z_3}=\frac{y_4-y_3}{x_4-x_3}=a(x_4^2+x_3x_4+x_3^2)+b(x_4+x_3)+c \tag 7$$

Repeat the process
$$\color{red}{w_1}=\frac{z_2-z_1}{x_3-x_1}=a(x_1+x_2+x_3)+b \tag 8$$
$$\color{red}{w_2}=\frac{z_3-z_2}{x_4-x_2}=a(x_2+x_3+x_4)+b \tag 9$$
One more step
$$w_2-w_1=a(x_4-x_1) \qquad \implies \qquad \color{red}{a=\frac{w_2-w_1 }{x_4-x_1}} \tag {10}$$

Go back to $(9)$ to obtain $\color{red}{b}$; go back to $(7)$ to obtain $\color{red}{c}$; go back to $(4)$ to obtain $\color{red}{d}$.

$$\huge\color{red}{\text{End of the story}}$$

Comment: I'm going to respectfully disagree - Software can help gain insight. Also, I don't think this answers OP's question.

Comment: @SeanRoberson. There is a major problem with democracy : we may disagree ! What I mean is that, at a low level, it is much better to do the work by yourself instead of blindly use a software (multiple jokes since I am really blind). Later, when you know how to get the solution, software makes life easier. Cheers (and forget the respect - go back to my first statement).  :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that's truly admirable.

Comment: @James. Thank you ! I hope and wish that you will make every effort in order I get the Fields medal for this more than admirable work. PS: Gosh, I am $2.025$ times too old for it (I forgot). Cheers :-)

Comment: $$\huge\color{red}{\text{End of the story}}$$ has got to be the funniest thing I've seen on this site in a while.